# How to use both URI segments and Query strings without enabling: enable_query_strings

Tags: php, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter it's really tricky to combine URI segments and Query strings at the same time.
One of the traditional ways to almost achieve that is by enabling `enable_query_strings`.

The issue is that this has some weird behavior and it affects all the URL helpers as well.

By example when using: `redirect('/home')` it redirects to `domain.com/?/home`.

Based on my knowledge, `enable_query_strings` is not meant to be used with URI segments.

So how to extend the core to enable both GET and URI out of the box?

*P.S. I know that it's better to just use URI segments, but it's very important sometimes to accept GET queries like from adwords.*

Comment: I'm right there with you, sometimes you need $_GET. There's nothing at all wrong with "mixing" it with uri segments. Example: I want people to be able to link to search results that use a search term, entered by the user. How else could you support this if the user input contain characters not in your `permitted_uri_chars`? How about dealing with third-party responses that use `$_GET`? You **need** it sometimes, I have no idea why it was ever disabled in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution is this:

- Make sure you are on the latest version of CI, currently 2.0.2
- Forget about the misleading `enable_query_strings` (it's not what you want)
- Open your config file and set `allow_get_array` to `TRUE`, which will allow you to use `$_GET`
- Play with the `uri_protocol` setting until you find one that works for your environment, `PATH_INFO` works for me.
- Enjoy the use of proper query strings!

`enable_query_strings` breaks almost all the functionality that makes Codeigniter great, including *all* the helper functions that deal with urls. It was some experimental feature that has been confused with normal query string support for as long as CI has been around.

Bottom line - just upgrade (if you haven't already) and don't try to write a hack for it.

Comment: I need to be able to use the helpers (so I can have http://domain.com/user/account/edit) but also require the use of the query strings for accessing controllers and methods (http://domain.com?d=user&c=account&m=edit). Setting enable_query_strings to FALSE means I cannot use the latter at all, despite allow_get_array being TRUE. Is there a way I can huse both options and the URL helpers? (To add, I know the query strings can be used still when enable_query_strings is set to FALSE, but it seems to redirect to the URI version, which I don't want to happen)