# CodeIgniter QueryStrings

Tags: codeigniter, request.querystring

First of all I MUST point out that I am NOT a programmer, have NO desire to be a programmer, and the application i am speaking of was NOT written by me. I am just an average end user trying to make things work like I need them to work. That being said,

Two simple questions:

1.) Why will urls like this not work with codeigniter powered apps ?

http://somesite.com/search?q=something

2.) How do I force it to work like that ?

I have read atleast 2 dozen articles on the issue and NOTHING has worked. I have enabled QueryStrings in the config file, I have change the url_protocol to PATH_INFO, I have set my forms from post to get and NOTHING works.

HELP...

Comment: Why do you *need* a particular app to work with a certain kind of URL format? It all depends on the application really, but in most cases, you should be able to adapt.

Comment: I NEED it to work like this because I have another application that needs this behavior. I could simply write some very ugly code (since I am not a programmer an all) for the other application to make an exception for ALL codeigniter apps or I could just fix the problem that CI dev team seems to ignore and be done with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use both URI segments and Query strings without enabling: enable_query_strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693997/how-to-use-both-uri-segments-and-query-strings-without-enabling-enable-query-str)

Comment: The main issue is that you need to enable `allow_get_array` which is not introduced until version 2.0.2 (currently the latest version). `enable_query_strings`, although it *sounds* like it should do what it says, it completely different.

Comment: It's not a duplicate because I am NOT the developer in this case. I do not have codeigniter on my system. I am just an end user of an application I found on the net which was written with codeigniter.

Comment: @Mark: The answer is *in* the linked question. I've personally answered this question many many times, old versions of CI kill the `$_GET` array. If you have no control over the code, then it's pointless for you to even ask, especially with such a demanding attitude - however, you said you are able to edit the config so that makes no sense. If you need to hire a developer, try http://careers.stackoverflow.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try changing `$config['uri_protocol']   = "PATH INFO"; to $config['uri_protocol']   = "REQUEST_URI";`

If this still does not work, check your `.htaccess` file for a rule that removes `index.php` from URL; it will be of the form:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [L]
```

If this rule exists, change the last line to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Notice, the ? is removed from last line. 
Check after doing above steps. Hope this works.

Comment: I changed the protocol as suggested and tried again and got a 404 error when trying to load the page so I created an .htaccess file and copied and pasted the rules you posted into it and placed it in my scripts main folder and still got a 404 error. Next ...

Comment: CAn you post your routes.php file

Comment: @Mark, in your htaccess file, replace                        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [L] with                    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]                                                                                                   Notice, the absence of "?" in the above rule. this will surely work