# Codeigniter Query Strings URL Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, query-string, clean-urls

I have already setup project having it's url like below.

`index.php?c=controllerName&m=methodName`

And parameter in above url like below.

`index.php?c=controllerName&m=methodName&selDeg=manager`

I want to use url like below for my newely created modules.

`admin/Items/1`

But want to use first type url as it is for previousely developed modules.

Is it possible to use url with `index.php` for old modules and without `index.php` for new modules.

Comment: Dont think that can be done. That is configured in your config.php globally to your app, not just for some parts of it.

Comment: @marcogmonteiro Can it is possible using htaccess to define that all previous url can work with `index.php` and new without `index.php`?

Comment: Have a look at this [Use both segments and query strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693997/how-to-use-both-uri-segments-and-query-strings-without-enabling-enable-query-st)

Comment: @Yogendrasinh yeah probably but not 100% sure on this.

Comment: @SherifSalah I have done my config file and added below lines.
`$config['allow_get_array']  = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger']  = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';`

Also change `$config['uri_protocol']= 'AUTO';` To Other value and PATH_INFO is take effect but still i am not getting the result. The config not allow to work with both type of url at same time. Either it allows old url or new url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepare your config like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'your_base_url';
$config['index_page'] = ''; // empty string
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE; // keep it to default FALSE, you can use it even without enabling it here
```

and your `.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I think that is it, now you can use both `segments` and `query_strings` like this:

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/?c=welcome&m=index
http://localhost/codeigniter/welcome/index
http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/welcome/index
http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php?c=welcome&m=index
http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/?c=welcome&m=index
```

I've already tested both in my environment and it works just fine.

---

**Edit**: in my codeigniter template i've extended my core router and slightly changed the `_set_routing()` method like this:

Of course it is a bad practice to change the core system, so you need to extend the core router file and create `MY_Router.php` under `application/core` and make it extend `CI_Router` like this:

```
class MY_Router extends CI_Router
{
protected function _set_routing()
{
    if (file_exists(APPPATH.'config/routes.php'))
    {
        include(APPPATH.'config/routes.php');
    }

    if (file_exists(APPPATH.'config/'.ENVIRONMENT.'/routes.php'))
    {
        include(APPPATH.'config/'.ENVIRONMENT.'/routes.php');
    }

    if (isset($route) && is_array($route))
    {
        isset($route['default_controller']) && $this->default_controller = $route['default_controller'];
        isset($route['translate_uri_dashes']) && $this->translate_uri_dashes = $route['translate_uri_dashes'];
        unset($route['default_controller'], $route['translate_uri_dashes']);
        $this->routes = $route;
    }

    $_c = trim($this->config->item('controller_trigger'));
    if ( ! empty($_GET[$_c]))
    {
        $this->uri->filter_uri($_GET[$_c]);
        $this->set_class($_GET[$_c]);

        $_f = trim($this->config->item('function_trigger'));
        if ( ! empty($_GET[$_f]))
        {
            $this->uri->filter_uri($_GET[$_f]);
            $this->set_method($_GET[$_f]);
        }

        $this->uri->rsegments = array(
            1 => $this->class,
            2 => $this->method
        );
    }
    else
    {
        if ($this->uri->uri_string !== '')
        {
            $this->_parse_routes();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_set_default_controller();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now you you have the best of both worlds, you will keep your segments with its goodies untouched but will always look for get `c=&m=`, i hope its clear enough.

We kept everything to default and made it check for a get request with `c` and `m` pretty like what `enable_query_strings` does but without enabling it and messing anything up to keep working with segments as it is..

Comment: Can you tell me which version you are using? I have set up new codeigniter 3.1.9 and did the changes that you mentioned as above but still i am not able to use both the URL in my setup.

Comment: I'm using codeigniter 3.1.9 too, and I've added all the urls I've used and all of them worked fine **out of the box** with the mentioned configurations.

Comment: Lemme check if i have extra configurations in my ci_template

Comment: Okay. With this configuration for me it runs only clean URL like `codeigniter/welcome/index` but when i pass url like `codeigniter/?c=welcome&m=index` it always going to the default route controller. I have change my default route as `$route['default_controller'] = 'test';`. so when i pass url with `c` and `m` then it always call my `test` controller's `index` method.

Comment: Look at the edits, now it works just fine but keep `$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;` @Yogendrasinh

Comment: You are changing core file method. Is it possible without changing directly in core file? Can it be possible to override that core method?

Comment: Just change the core like this for now and test it and we will discuss extending later!

Comment: I edited my answer again and explained how can you extend you core libraries, everything should be fine now. @Yogendrasinh